# Flash not working on OS X / iOS?

Tags: ios, macos, flash

I have a flash file (.swf) on the homepage of my web site. When a user loads the page, the file cycles through some images. It works as expected when I access the site from a Windows PC, but when I access it from either a Mac computer or an iPhone/iPad, there is a white space where the flash file should be. What usually causes this kind of behavior?

EDIT:

Did some more careful testing on my Mac (running OS X Version 10.6.8). The flash file **does not** work in the latest version of Safari with the latest Flash Player installed, but it **does** work in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, the answer to this question didn't have anything to do with the flash's code itself. The file in question was placed on the page by way of the < embed > element. As I discovered from reading [this rather old but still very relevant article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/flashsatay), < embed > is not supported in all browsers. Apparently, it's supported in Firefox but not in Chrome or Safari. After following the advice in that article, the flash file plays correctly in all flash-supporting browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Flash doesn't work on iOS, iOS does not support it.
As for OS X, what browser(s) have you tried and what versions of OS X?

Comment: I'm running OS X Verison 10.6.8. I just installed the latest version of Flash Player, and it still doesn't work in Safari. However, I also tried it in Firefox just now, and it shows up fine. I'm running the latest version of Safari (5.1.7).

Comment: I think so. I googled "test flash player" and went to a handful of sites, including the Adobe Flash download page itself, and everything seemed to work as expected.

Comment: @Andrew At this point it makes me think that the problem lies within your .swf as some sort of compatibility issue with your flash file and how safari handles flash.

Comment: Most likely. I didn't actually write the file myself though, so I don't know what all it has in it. I'll see if I can find the person who did and ask them about it.

Answer (score 0):

Running Flash from a web page is not supported in iOS (iPhone/iPad), likely your Mac OSX does not have the Flash Player plugin.